# How to center-align image link and make it clickable only on image not overflowing area?

Tags: html, css, image

I created a image link:-

```css
    .post-image {
      margin: 20px auto;
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

```html
 <a href="example.com/link">
       <img class="post-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKSXt.jpg" />
    </a>
```

But the link is clickable outside the image also.

How can I center-align the image and also make the link clickable only on the image not outside the image (overflowing area).

[Centered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rC2A.jpg)

Comment: try using .post-image{ display: inline-block;} instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: inline;` to image `.post-image` to get it centered and add `text-align: center;` to tha parent of `a` tag

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.post-image {
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: inline;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKSXt.jpg">
    <img class="post-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKSXt.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: it's still the same in the problem

Comment: Worked perfectly...! 
I placed the image link inside a <div> and added the css of the body tag you suggested.

Comment: @MuthuKrishnan no, you can to it with your existing `div` itself, dont add body inside a div. thats a wrong thing. see my updated answer. upvote & accept the answer if it helped, so that it would be useful for some other one like you

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is acceptable, but I use `{display: inline-block}`

**Edit:** *Just noticed you want the image to be centered too. Edited code to reflect*

```css
body {
  text-align: center
}
.post-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="example.com/link">
    <img class="post-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKSXt.jpg" />
  </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Way:

Simply use `Position:Absolute`. And if you have any other elements in the page. `position:absolute` may affect their visibility.

```css
.post-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com/link">
  <img class="post-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKSXt.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thats a different solution bro (y)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div before `href` tag and add `text-align: center;` on this div. like:

```
.post-image {
      margin: 20px auto;
      display: inline-block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
}

<div style="text-align: center;">
<a href="example.com/link">
       <img class="post-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKSXt.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```